# Google search with python is sporadically non-accurate and has Type Errors

Tags: python, json, google-api, google-search

I am using some code I found here on SO to google search a set of strings and return the "expected" amount of results. Here is that code:

```
for a in months:
    for b in range(1, daysInMonth[a] + 1):

        #Code

        if not myString:
            googleStats.append(None)
        else:
            try:
            query = urllib.urlencode({'q': myString})
            url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
            search_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
            search_results = search_response.read()
            results = json.loads(search_results)
            data = results['responseData']           
            googleStats.append(data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
        except TypeError:
            googleStats.append(None)
for x in range(0, len(googleStats)):
    if googleStats[x] != None:
        finalGoogleStats.append(googleStats[x])
```

There are two problems, which may be related. When I return the len(finalGoogleStats), it's different every time. One time it's 37, then it's 12. However, it should be more like 240.

This is TypeError I receive when I take out the try/except:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

which occurs on line

```
googleStats.append(data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
```

So, I just can't figure out why the number of Nones in googleStats changes every time and it's never as low as it should be. If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them, thanks!

**UPDATE**

When I try to print out data for every think I'm searching, I get a ton of Nones and very, very few actual JSON dictionaries. The dictionaries I do get are spread out across all the searches, I don't see a pattern in what is a None and what isn't. So, the problem looks like it has more to do with GoogleAPI than anything else.

Comment: Why catch `TypeError` then?

Comment: You should publish a little bit more of your code. I expect this part is inside a loop otherwise `len(googleStats)` will be 0 or 1. It seems also like sometimes `data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount']` is `None`

Comment: I added more code, hope it helps. @MartijnPieters, I caught it because it came up when I ran it the first time, I thought it would only happen once or twice, but it's happening around 400/420 times...

Comment: @furins, what makes you say that sometimes data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'] is None? That may very well be what my issue is

Comment: I was guessing you had some clean-up code. Actually you have, they are the last three lines you added to your question. The reason you're getting `None` as results may be due to google API implementation. I do not know google apis enough to help you on this.

Comment: We cannot tell, you didn't share the `TypeError` exception you see. I *suspect* that something in the JSON data structure is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: Indeed, you should log google's responses to see if it is like you expected. The `TypeError\ exception should also rise a warning to let you better understand what's happening.

Comment: More details please - you can use Python debugger to debug btw. It is pdb. search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is what I was fearing for a while, but thanks to everyone who tried to help, I upvoted you if anythign was useful.

So, Google seems to randomly freak out that I'm searching so must stuff. Here's the error they give to me :

```
Suspected Terms of Service Abuse ...... responseStatus:403
```

So, I guess they put limits on how much I can search with them. What is still strange, though, is that it doesn't happen all the time, I still get sporadic successful searches within the sea of errors. That is still a mystery...

Comment: Maybe this API endpoint is rate limited? To interact with any 3rd party API through HTTP, diagnosing through the response code and error messages is often useful (and also `try..except` those to handle them). Based on the error response, I'd say it's not a mystery, it's indeed "rate limit" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd say remove your `try..except` clause and see where exactly the problem is. Then as a general good practice, when you try to access layers of dictionary elements, use `.get()` method instead for better control.

As a demonstration of your possible `TypeError`, here is my educated guess:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a['lol'] = None
>>> a['lol']['teemo']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
```

There are ways to use `.get()`, for a simple demonstration:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> b = a.get('lol')  # will return None
>>> if type(b) is dict:  # determine type
...     print b.get('teemo')  # same technique if b is indeed of type dict
... 
>>>
```

Comment: Yep, just added it. That's the correct error. How would I use the .get() here?

Comment: Could you update your question with a working code? Just need it to be comprehensive enough to cover the problems you're talking about.

Comment: Not sure what you mean working code, the code above runs and works, it just has a bunch of "None"s where there should be JSON dicts, try/except just allows me to run the entire program without it crashing, then I can see just how many JSON dicts I'm getting. It was 3/~420 last time :p

Answer (score 1):

By default the googleapi pass the least result. If you want to increase your display results, in your url add another parameter 'rsz=8' (by default rsz=1 hence the small result).

so your new url becomes:

url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=8&%s' % query

see detailed documentation here: https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/reference#_class_GSearch